# Can we add EULA to iOS in later binary revision?

Tags: ios, app-store, eula

I am going to submit my first app on app store. I want to hold my app's customized EULA as of now so that approval process is not slow and later add my EULA in the next revision. Am I allowed to do so?
Also, just uploading customized EULA while submitting application is enough? or I have to present a view in my app so that users can tap Agree to?

Answer (score 7):

You can change to a customized EULA whenever you want (in iTunes Connect, click Manage Your Applications, then click the app to edit, then View Details, then scroll to the bottom where it says EULA and click Edit).

All this does is add a link below the description ("Application License Agreement"), which will display your EULA if clicked.  If you require the user to click Agree, you have to do that in your app, according to the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf):

> End User License Agreement (EULA) — this must be consistent with the minimum iTunes terms and
>   conditions. If you need the user to explicitly accept, do so from within your app.